# Google +1 Button errors in implementation in Android

Tags: android, button, google-plus-one

I'm trying to add Google +1 Button to my Android app. I have some problems with it. I do everything what is in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started, next what is in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend but without any results. When I'm using the app code from second link I get NullPointerException... How could it work? Google made a mistake or what? Also, after importing lib, in layout when I put Google Plus Button - I had error like " Unable to instantiate...". What should I do? Example app in sdk is not working for me (NullPointerException?!) . The same thing is when I initialize mPlusOneButton and mPlusClient  before calling mPlusOneButton.initialize in onResume. Anyone got it work?

Comment: Logcat output might be useful.

Comment: I can't run app, so what logcat are you talking about

Comment: You've mentioned NullPointerException. How have You observed it without logcat? And it's better to have single question instead of multiple random questions across the post.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the sample code, if you're getting the NullPointer Exception at findViewById, I think you forgot to add the setContentView call in onCreate.

Can't really guess anything else without looking at the code and logcat.